# Finding limits when given $2$ different limits.

Tags: calculus, limits, fractions

> Let $\lim\limits_{x\to -1} f(x) = 8$ and $\lim\limits_{x\to -1} g(x) =-4$. Find $\lim\limits_{x\to -1} \dfrac{f(x)}{g(x)}$.

Answer Choices are:

A. $-2$

B. $12$

C. $-1/2$

D. $-1$

I started out trying to solve this problem by attempting to use a derivative formula which just overcomplicated the problem and did not lead me to any of the potential answer choices.

I was struggling with this problem as I did not understand the limit laws and upon further review I understood them well enough to realize that I should have just simply plugged in my $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ values to get my final answer of $-2$.

Is this okay?

Comment: It's supposed to be lim x to -1 of f(x)=8 and lim x to -1 of g(x)=-4. Find lim x to -1 f(x)/g(x)

Comment: This is a straightforward problem using basic properties of limits (limit of the quotient is the quotient of the limit, when both limits exist and limit of denominator is not 0). Is there some specific question you have about it?

Comment: This is my first week of calculus and thus I am having some difficulty getting started on the problem. Any tips of how to approach it would be appreciated.

Comment: Given my verbal description of the property of limits that you would want to use, what can you conclude the answer is?

Comment: From what you have said I believe that the answer is -2

Comment: That's correct.

Answer (score 2):

Using the limit rules and the help provided by other people I was able to determine that the final answer is -2

I also realize now that I way over thinking this question. It has been a long day of math I am sorry for asking such an obvious one when the answer was as right in front of me in the form of basic math.

Answer (score 0):

**hint:** $\lim\limits_{x\to c} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\frac{L}{H}$ where $\lim_{x\to c}f(x)=L$ and provided $\lim_{x\to c}g(x)=H\not = 0$

Comment: With such a short hint, maybe include that (for the truth of this in general) the limits on the right exist and the denominator limit not be $0.$